# The Glitch Effect I'm working on isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a glitchy text effect for a website. On Stackoverflow it works completes fine. Good so far.

But the Problem is in my project folder it doesn't. If you want to check it out, heres a link to download it:
[Download](http://www.mediafire.com/file/crw2gu7uh1cfum7/website.zip/file)

Here's the HTML, CSS and jQuery code:

```js
$(document).ready(
  $('.textglitch').hover(function(){
    var eLtext = $(this).text(), eLchild = $(this).find('.textglitch-link');
    //console.log(eLchild);
    eLchild.attr('data-content', eLtext);
    eLchild.toggleClass('blur');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  }));
```

```css
/*----TAGS----*/

*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', monospace;
}

body{
  background-color: black;
  background: repeat url("../img/noise.gif");
  outline:none;
  list-style:none;
  text-decoration:none;
}

/*----CLASS----*/

.main_div{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/*----ANIMATE----*/

.textglitch {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 5vw;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.textglitch .textglitch-link {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.textglitch-link span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
}

.blur {
  filter: blur(1px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
}

.textglitch .textglitch-link:after,
.textglitch .textglitch-link:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  content: attr(data-content);
  visibility: hidden;
}

.textglitch.active .textglitch-link:after,
.textglitch.active .textglitch-link:before {
  visibility: visible;
}

.textglitch .textglitch-link:before {
  color: rgba(255, 0, 188, 0.8);
  -webkit-animation: textglitch .3s cubic-bezier(.25, .46, .45, .94) both infinite;
  animation: textglitch .3s cubic-bezier(.25, .46, .45, .94) both infinite;
}


.textglitch .textglitch-link:after {
  color: rgba(0,255,255,0.8);
  -webkit-animation: textglitch .3s cubic-bezier(.25, .46, .45, .94) reverse both infinite;
  animation: textglitch .3s cubic-bezier(.25, .46, .45, .94) reverse both infinite;
}

@keyframes textglitch {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
    transform: translate(0)
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 3px);
    transform: translate(-3px, 3px)
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, -3px);
    transform: translate(-3px, -3px)
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(3px, 3px);
    transform: translate(3px, 3px)
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(3px, -3px);
    transform: translate(3px, -3px)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
    transform: translate(0)
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/theme.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/master.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <div class="main_div">
      <div class="textglitch">
        <a class="textglitch-link"><span>This is a Test</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would be glad if someone could help me to fix this problem.

Comment: you are calling the jQuery after your JS. Do the opposite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at your code and it has the following problems:

1. The main file must be called `index.html` and it must be stored in teh root - it cannot be in a subfolder. Therefore, you will need to also update your links in the `<head>` (ie. `js/master.js` not `../js/master.js` ***and*** `css/theme.css` not `../css/theme.css`)
2. Change your js code to:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){  //<=== i.e. missing the: " function(){ "
      $('.textglitch').hover(
        function(){
            var eLtext = $(this).text(), eLchild = $(this).find('.textglitch-link');
            console.log(eLchild);
            eLchild.attr('data-content', eLtext);
            eLchild.toggleClass('blur');
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
        });
    });
```

3. Make sure jQuery is loaded before the `master.js` file.

```
    <body>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/master.js"></script>


      <div class="main_div">
```